# Timing of model testing and training of a decision tree classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I obtained the multi-class classification summary using Decision Tree classifier with the code below,

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=17)
classifier.fit(train_x, train_Y)

pred_y = classifier.predict(test_x)
print(classification_report(test_Y,pred_y))
accuracy_score(test_Y,pred_y)
```

the output did not have any figure on time for testing or training the data set. 
[image]

How can I get the testing time and training time of the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some scikit-Learn models do have a *verbose* parameter, which allow you to control the level of verbosity of the fitting process, including the timings, see some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443041/predicting-how-long-an-scikit-learn-classification-will-take-to-run). But that is not the case of the `DecisionTreeClassifier`. Though a simple thing you can do, is just timing it yourself:

```
import time

start_time = time.time()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print(f'{elapsed_time:.2f}s elapsed during training')
```

Or you could wrap it with a [`Pipeline`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html), setting  verbose to a value higher than `0` (note that the interesting feature from sklearn's pipeline is to encapsulate the list of transformations to apply in a sequential manner and the final estimator):

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

pipe = Pipeline([('tree', DecisionTreeClassifier())], verbose=3)
pipe.set_params(tree__random_state=17).fit(X_train, y_train)
```